# Compare HTML input tag value with Jinja2 element

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I am fetching a list of directories  in a ***{{ directory }}*** tag using **Python** and **Jinja2** template, and I want to add a new directory using input tag, but before adding the new directory I want to check if that directory already exists.

My code:

```
<a href="/?directory_name={{ directory }}" class="table1">
{{ directory }}
</a>
<input type="text" class="text_input" name="value" id="t_input">
<button onclick="compare_input();">Add New dir</button>
<script>
    // Compare two input fields 
    function compare_input()
    {
        var f_input=document.getElementById('{{ directory }}').value;
        var s_input=document.getElementById('t_input').value;
        if(f_input===s_input)
        {
            alert('Directory already exist.enter a new name');
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have googled already how to compare a Python tag with an HTML input value, but did not get any proper example.

**Expected Result:**
If a user types "book" into the input text field and then clicks on the "Add New dir" button, and the **book** directory already exists such as

[book](https://book)
[cities](https://cities)

then an alert prompt should be displayed to the user like **"Directory already exists, enter another name"**.

Comment: would mind explaining the problem with some example of what do you actually want to achieve? (Not going to hurt your dog by any means:P )

Comment: i am trying to make an app to store data online such as google drive.and in that app i am creating directories(folders).before creating new folder i want to check if a folder exists or not .if it exists then prompt to user that you can not create a folder(directory) with same name.

Comment: is this all of the code? I don't see looping of `{{ directory }}`, or any element with id of `{{ directory }}`. Why are you getting element by id when you can just use `{{ directory }}`?

Comment: sorry to say ,i assumed {{ directory }} here as a list of values and  did not show loops and un-necessary code here.

Comment: @jhon_wick can you show the Page source code after the page is rendered ?